# Prove area under curve is between two values

Tags: calculus

The question reads:

Prove that $$0 \leq \int_\frac{\pi}{4}^\frac{\pi}{2} \frac{\sin(x)}{x} \, dx \leq \frac{\sqrt2}{2} \ .$$

I know that I should apply $$ m(b-a) \leq \int_a^b f(x) \, dx \leq M(b-a)$$
where $ m \leq f(x) \leq M $ on $[a, b]$.

If this where simply $\sin(x)$ it would easier to evaluate, but dividing by the x term is throwing me off. Any suggestions on where to start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint 1:

$$f(x)=\dfrac{\sin{x}}{x}\le f(\dfrac{\pi}{4})$$
because $f'(x)<0,x\in (\pi/4,\pi/2)$

Hint 2
Use Cauchy-Schwarz inequality
$$\int_{\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\dfrac{\sin{x}}{x}dx\le\sqrt{\int_{\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sin^2{x}dx\int_{\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{1}{x^2}dx}=\sqrt{\dfrac{\pi+2}{4\pi}}<\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$$